# How to disable the unused port in istio operator

Tags: istio, istio-operator

I want to follow the best practices and disable the unused ports. But I am not able to figure out where exactly to disable. I am using Istio operator to deploy `istiod`.

I want to set flag `grpcAddr=""` in controlplane and also remove/disable unused ports 15090, 15021, 15020 and 15000 in dataplane.

```
kubectl apply -f - <<EOF
apiVersion: install.istio.io/v1alpha1
kind: IstioOperator
metadata:
  namespace: istio-system
  name: example-istiocontrolplane
spec:
  profile: minimal
EOF
```

```
Control Plane
Istiod exposes a few unauthenticated plaintext ports for convenience by default. If desired, these can be closed:

Port 8080 exposes the debug interface, which offers read access to a variety of details about the clusters state. This can be disabled by set the environment variable ENABLE_DEBUG_ON_HTTP=false on Istiod. Warning: many istioctl commands depend on this interface and will not function if it is disabled.
Port 15010 exposes the XDS service over plaintext. This can be disabled by adding the --grpcAddr="" flag to the Istiod Deployment. Note: highly sensitive services, such as the certificate signing and distribution services, are never served over plaintext.

Data Plane
The proxy exposes a variety of ports. Exposed externally are port 15090 (telemetry) and port 15021 (health check). Ports 15020 and 15000 provide debugging endpoints. These are exposed over localhost only. As a result, the applications running in the same pod as the proxy have access; there is no trust boundary between the sidecar and application.
```